# Send message to encrypted SQS queue from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-policies, amazon-kms

I have a AWS Lambda function that needs to send messages to an encrypted SQS queue. At one point I got it working that my AWS Lambda function could send messages to this encrypted SQS queue. After I got it working I made some adjustments to the permissions so they are more specific. Then it suddenly stopped working even after I reverted back to the really broad permissions.

Now I always get this following error:

```
KMS.AccessDeniedException: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access.
```

My CMK has the following policy and ONLY allows in it:

```
    {
        "Sid": "Allow specific lambda to use this key",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:lambda:XXXXXX:function:XXXXXX"
    }
```

*I redacted the resource but I triple checked the ARN and it is correct.*

My Lambda function has the following policy attached to it:

```
    {
        "Action": "sqs:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Action": "kms:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
```

Shouldn't this be enough for my Lambda to send a message to this SQS queue? Like I mentioned above at one point this worked than I tried to restrict the policies on my Lambda and then it stopped working even after I changed it back.

What am I missing here? I'm not sure what else I could change and why it worked and then it stopped working...

---

**Edit**

Permissions that seemed to work and now doesn't:

**CMK policy**

```
{
    "Sid": "Allow AWS Lambda to use this key",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Action": [
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
    ],
    "Resource": "*"
}
```

**Lambda Policy**

```
{
    "Action": "sqs:*",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Effect": "Allow"
},
{
    "Action": "kms:*",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

---

**Edit 2**

There has to be something in play that I don't understand because this doesn't behave predictable...

I made the following changes with CDK:

First change:

```
IAM Statement Changes
┌───┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│   │ Resource │ Effect │ Action              │ Principal                                                        │ Condition │
├───┼──────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ + │ *        │ Allow  │ kms:GenerateDataKey │ AWS:${lambda---------------------------------------/ServiceRole} │           │
└───┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Result: I can send messages to the SQS queue again

Second change:

```
IAM Statement Changes
┌───┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│   │ Resource │ Effect │ Action              │ Principal                                                        │ Condition │
├───┼──────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ - │ *        │ Allow  │ kms:GenerateDataKey │ AWS:${lambda---------------------------------------/ServiceRole} │           │
├───┼──────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ + │ *        │ Allow  │ kms:*               │ AWS:${lambda---------------------------------------/ServiceRole} │           │
└───┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Result: I can't send messages to the SQS queue anymore ?!? Why?

Third change:

```
IAM Statement Changes
┌───┬──────────┬────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬───────────┐
│   │ Resource │ Effect │ Action              │ Principal                                                        │ Condition │
├───┼──────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ - │ *        │ Allow  │ kms:*               │ AWS:${lambda---------------------------------------/ServiceRole} │           │
├───┼──────────┼────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┤
│ + │ *        │ Allow  │ kms:GenerateDataKey │ AWS:${lambda---------------------------------------/ServiceRole} │           │
└───┴──────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

Result: I still can't send messages to the SQS queue anymore ?!? What is happening here? It is the same policy state as with the first change....

Comment: What where the permissions that worked?

Comment: @Marcin I added the permissions that seemed to work in my edit. I don't understand why this worked and now it doesn't.... maybe it shouldn't have worked but I can see the message in my SQS queue.

Comment: Have you added  ```const key = new kms.Key(this, "MyKey");``` and  ```key.grant(func, "kms:Decrypt", "kms:GenerateDataKey");``` in your lambda?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL my function has/had a policy with "kms:Decrypt" and "kms:GenerateDataKey"... I added a new edit to my post... it behaves unpredictable....